# Error: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'. > No matching client found for package name 'com.xx.xxx.xxxx'

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I got an error when I tried to sync my project with Gradle files

Here is the error

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'. No
>   matching client found for package name 'com.xx.xxx.xxxx'

Here is my Gradle file content:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.xx.xxx.xxxx"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0.3"
    testInstrumentationRunner  "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {

compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'

compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.4'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.4'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.4'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.4'

compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
provided 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.12.6'
compile 'org.parceler:parceler-api:1.0.4'
apt 'org.parceler:parceler:1.0.4'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.1'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.1.0'
compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.0'
compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
compile 'com.google.maps:google-maps-services:0.2.5'
compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-nop:1.7.25'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
compile 'com.cocosw:bottomsheet:1.+@aar'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And I have checked my google-service file package name and application id,both are same but when I tried to build the app, above mentioned error occured. My google-services file contains multiple projects including this one.

Please help me to fix it.

Comment: check my answer if it helps you, it would be great if you provide and app grandle too

Comment: checkout simple solution in answer given by me hope it's quit helpful

Answer (score 0):

First of all, go to `android/app/build.gradle` and search for `applicationId` (within `android`, `defaultConfig`)

and ensure that that value is the same this

`client[0]client_info.android_client_info.package_name`

as the value within `google-services.json`.

Then, try to update Project grandle (to the latest version) like below:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
```

Also update firebase dependencies like (pick what you need), this is based the latest version [of this link](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android):

```
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-functions:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:16.0.0'
```

And this is grandle app file, (pick what you need) based on [this link](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup):

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5'
```

Comment: @ClickSolApps so you have same problem and this is not working?

Answer (score 0):

Simply go to Firebase Console and create new project and add a new app with your desired `com.xx.xxx.xxxx` package name and get `google-services.json` file against that package name and add that file to your app module and rebuild or if you don't want to add that `.json` file then simply remove `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` from you gradle file and build your project again.